# Spinor method in massless limit

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

I have this problem where I'm asked to derive an explicit solution for the Dirac equation of massless fermion $p_\mu \gamma^\mu u(p)=0$. I'm instructed to do so by writing $p_\mu \gamma^\mu$ in the basis
$$ \gamma^0= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \gamma^i= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\sigma^i \\ \sigma^i & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \gamma^5= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$
After the solution is found, I'm asked to show $u_\pm^\dagger u_\pm=2p^0$.
When I write  $p_\mu \gamma^\mu $ using the a=basis above and put in the Dirac equation I get 4 equations for 4 components of the spinor $u(p)$, but because the equations are dependent (as in the massive case) I can't really solve it and only have a relations between $u^0$ and $u^1$ and $u^2$ and $u^3$ - two relations per each pair. I tried using all of the relations to write u(p) and to calculate  $u_\pm^\dagger u_\pm$ but I can't get what I need to show, i.e.  $u_\pm^\dagger u_\pm=2p^0$. Any ideas what I'm missing? Am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the general particle solutions of the Dirac Equation :

$$
u(\vec{p},s) = \sqrt{E+m} \begin{bmatrix} \phi^{(s)} \\  \frac{\vec{\sigma}.\vec{p}}{E+m} \phi^{(s)} \end{bmatrix}  
$$

Consider $m=0$ & calculate $u^{\dagger}(\vec{p},+)u(\vec{p},+)$ and $u^{\dagger}(\vec{p},-)u(\vec{p},-)$ with $\phi^{(s)}$ given as :

$$
\phi^{(+)} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \text{  and  } \phi^{(-)} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

You will easily get your answer.

Comment: Also, solving it your way, you just need to use the Dirac Equation and then you will be able to obtain the required answer.

Comment: I'm asked to derive the solution, not to use the general solution and substitute m=0.

Comment: Please try to think how these are different. They are not. If you have ever derived solutions of massive Dirac Equation then this follows exactly the same procedure. Also, do keep in mind the matrix dimensions. You can take $u(p) = \begin{bmatrix} \phi \\ \chi \end{bmatrix} e^{(-i p.x)}$. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Do keep in mind that you are not in Dirac basis, so your solutions would be just a bit different.

Comment: I'm probably missing something trivial here. If I follow the same approach as in the massive case, I get the system of two homogenous matrix equations of the form $p_\mu \sigma^\mu \phi =0 $ and as far as I understand it has only the trivial solution....